# Picture manipulation after capture

Tags: android, rotation, android-camera, crop

I need your help, if you are kind enough, into an issue that I'm having with my Android app:

I've managed to capture a picture in my MainActivity and display it into an separate activity - PictureActivity. My code is as follows:

In my **MainActivity** i have

```java
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

/**
 * This is called in tap on a graphic element in my MainActivity layout
 */
public void launchCamera(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Bitmap imageData = null;

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                Intent i = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("captured_picture", imageData);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.picture_capture_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

My **PictureActivity** looks like this:

```java
public class PictureActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture);

        Bitmap bitmap  = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("captured_picture");

        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview_photo);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My **PictureActivity layout** looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the final result looks so far:

[image: PictureActivity screen preview]

Long story short, these are the **things I want to do** next:

- rotate the picture if the user taps on the middle button from the main action bar
- crop the picture if the user taps on the first button from the left

Next, save the image somewhere (in shared preferences or session maybe?) and, aftewords, upload it to a remote server. I say "*save the image somewhere*" because the user can chose to take a second picture (from a maximum of two) and perform the same action, as above, on it (by taping on the first button from the right, in the main action bar).

What **I can't figure out** so far is:

- how do I know what is the current image (that I see on my screen)
- how can I set it's name and it's location where it should be saved to until I upload it to the remote server
- how can I manipulate it when I tap on one of the two buttons (*crop* or *rotate*)

Sorry for the long post and thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 3 questions:

1. The current image you see is in your devices RAM. Its the bitmap object which holds the data.
2. You have to save the bitmap to your devices storage
3. you have to transform your bitmap before saving it to storage

Here is some code which might help you:

```
public static void saveBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, String filename){
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

public static Bitmap cropAndRotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect cropRect, int rotateByDegrees) {
        Log.v(TAG, "cropAndRotateBitmap()");
        Log.v(TAG, "bitmap: " + bitmap);
        //Log.v(TAG, "orientation: " + orientation);
        Log.v(TAG, "degrees: " + rotateByDegrees);
        Log.v(TAG, "cropRect: " + cropRect);
        int cropRectWidth = cropRect.right - cropRect.left;
        int cropRectHeight = cropRect.bottom - cropRect.top;

        System.gc();

        Bitmap result;
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        if (rotateByDegrees == 0) {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropRectWidth, cropRectHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            m.postTranslate(-cropRect.left, -cropRect.top);

        } else if (rotateByDegrees == 90) {
            Log.v(TAG, "rotate 90, cropRect: " + cropRect);
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropRectHeight, cropRectWidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            m.postTranslate(-cropRect.left, -cropRect.height() - cropRect.top);
            m.postRotate(90);

        } else if (rotateByDegrees == 180) {
            Log.v(TAG, "rotate 180");
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropRectWidth, cropRectHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            m.postTranslate(-cropRect.left - cropRect.width(), -cropRect.height() - cropRect.top);
            m.postRotate(180);

        } else { // 270
            Log.v(TAG, "rotate 270");
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropRectHeight, cropRectWidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            m.postTranslate(-cropRect.width() - cropRect.left, -cropRect.top);
            m.postRotate(270);

        }
        Paint whitePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        whitePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, whitePaint);
        // canvas.restore();
        return result;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int rotateByDegrees) {

        Log.v(TAG, "rotateBitmap()");
        Log.v(TAG, "degrees: " + rotateByDegrees);

        System.gc();

        Bitmap result;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        if (rotateByDegrees == 0) {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            canvas.save();
        } else if (rotateByDegrees == 90) {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(90);
            canvas.translate(0, -1 * bitmap.getHeight());
        } else if (rotateByDegrees == 180) {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(180);
            canvas.translate(-1 * bitmap.getWidth(), -1 * bitmap.getHeight());
        } else { // 270
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(result);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(270);
            canvas.translate(-1 * bitmap.getWidth(), 0);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.restore();
        return result;
    }
```